# Normal Distribution Application

Tags: normal-distribution

Given: $\mu=80$, $\sigma=15$, $500$ respondents

**a.** Find $P(74\lt x \lt 101)$

**b.** Find number of respondents with score $\lt 98$

> For **a.**, my answer is $0.5746$ (using the formula $z=\cfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$); for **b.**, $442$ respondents (using the formula $z=\cfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ and multiplying the answer by $500$ respondents).

This question is flashed in our automated quiz where I got a score of $0$. I wanted to insist that I got the correct answers when we get back to class. May I verify them? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the formula $z=\cfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$?

Comment: true. how are you supposed to format fractions here? is there a thread that discuss formatting in stackexhange? that's my usual concern when posting problems. kindly edit the post. thanks!

Comment: Its okay, it takes a while to get used to:)

Comment: I got $.5747$ for the first.  Well, $0.574665082...$ so perhaps there is a rounding issue?  I got $442.465..$ for the second, so I'd have also said $442$.A good formatting tutorial is:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Florencio Lulu and myself have verified your answer, so I would say you are totally correct. Unless your waiting for further confirmation?

Comment: With your verification, I was encouraged to appeal this when we get back to class. Thank you for taking your time! :)

Comment: @Florencio You're welcome, enjoy your day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part **a.** I get $P(74\lt x \lt 101) = P\left(\cfrac{74-80}{15} \lt z \lt \cfrac{101-80}{15}\right)=0.574665082$.

For part **b.** I get $P(x \lt 98)\times 500 = P\left(-99 \lt z \lt \cfrac{98-80}{15}\right) \times 500\approx 0.885\times500=442.5$. For this I just used the fact that the at the end of the left tail of the Gaussian it takes large and negative $z$. So I chose $-99$ (ideally this should be $-\infty$ but this is undefined).

Comment: I believe the OP intends s.d. to be 15, sample size to be 500.  (full disclosure:  I did exactly the same thing you did at first).

Comment: @lulu thank you for pointing that out lulu :)

Comment: the comma was intended to separate the given values (not to indicate thousands) where there are 500 respondents and the standard deviation is 15.

Comment: @Florencio Okay understood, thanks for letting me know